# ADDING FAUX STONE TO CONCRETE FOUNDATION

Tags: stone

WANT TO FACE FOUNDATION WITH "EVOLVE STONE".  BLOCK HAS THIN MORTAR FACING AND IS PAINTED.
"EVOLVE STONE" DOESNT THINK THE PRIMER AND GLUE THAT NEEDS TO BE USED WILL ADHERE TO THE PAINT.  THINKING ABOUT HARDIE OR OTHER CONCRETE BOARD ATTACHED BY POWER GUN. MOST AREAS LESS THAN 2 FEET HIGH,  PORCH AREA 32INCHES.  STONE WUD BUTT UP TO VINYL 1.5 INCH J CHANNEL SO CANT DO FIRRING. ANY THOUGHTS/SUGGESTIONS.

Comment: A pic of the area you are working on would help us understand better.  Maybe it would be easier to grind off the paint.  Also , why are you yelling? ( using all caps)

Comment: It is very hard to read, so many will not read it.  Please edit and use normal case and add pictures.

Comment: Typing in all-caps has been considered as shouting since the dawn of the internet. Please don’t shout at us.

Answer (score 1):

Is paint removal something you'd entertain? There's no worry about damaging the surface since it'll be covered with new materials. An angle grinder with a knotted wire cup brush or a diamond concrete grinding disc might make quick work of it.

Comment: adding Hardie, no way. Monkey and a grinder, +1. Do it when your neighbors aren't home.